# reveal.js and hilightjs - how to stop my tags from being automatically closed

Tags: javascript, html, reveal.js, highlight.js

I am making a presentation using reveal.js

I want to display the following in a nice syntax highlighted code block:

```
<foo>
```

So in my presentation html I do this:

```
<pre><code class="hljs" data-trim contenteditable>
<foo>
</code></pre>
```

This is what gets displayed instead:

```
<foo>
</foo>
```

How do I stop my tags from getting closed for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<pre><code class="hljs" data-trim contenteditable>
&ltfoo>
</code></pre>
```